# Where are passwords stored in a unix file system?

Tags: unix, passwords

Where are passwords stored in unix file systems?

Are they directly stored in etc directory or in further directory - and who can view the unencrypted passwords?

Comment: Takke a look at this post http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37050/where-is-my-password-stored-on-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older UNIX variants stored the encrypted passwords in `/etc/passwd` along with other information about each account.

Newer ones simply have a `*` in the relevant field in `/etc/passwd` and use `/etc/shadow` to store the password, in part to ensure nobody gets read access to the passwords when they only need the other stuff (`shadow` is usually protected more strongly than `passwd`).

Anyone with enough power on the box can see unencrypted passwords, by examining memory directly, or replacing the `login` program or any one of a dozen other methods. But, to be honest, if they're that powerful, they already have all your files so the password is irrelevant (unless you use the same password on multiple systems).

You may also find passwords stored in a central repository such as LDAP, which removes the passwords from the individual boxes entirely.

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

1. If the UNIX box is managing its own passwords locally, it will be in `/etc/shadow` (though in ye olden days we used `/etc/passwd`. root is the only user that can access the file, and its only stored in hashed form.
2. If using centralized passwords, you may find a few shops doing NIS/NIS+ but most will be using LDAP, and in that case the password is stored in a centralized LDAP directory (OpenLDAP, Active Directory, etc.), again, in hashed form.

Plaintext passwords are a relic of the past and if exists, indicates some hackery, or some local poorly written app.

Answer (score 3):

Passwords in unix were originally stored in `/etc/passwd` (which is world-readable), but then moved to `/etc/shadow` (and backed up in  /etc/shadow-) which can only be read by root (or members of the shadow group).

The password are salted and hashed. The default formats are `MD5-crypt, bcrypt, sha256-crypt, sha512-crypt`, and for historical reasons DES (note DES only allows 8-byte passwords). Note, sha512-crypt is typically involves 5000 rounds of SHA512-ing the password and the number of rounds is configurable.

For more info consult `man crypt, man shadow, man passwd`.

Answer (score 1):

Password hashes were traditionally stored in `/etc/passwd` , but modern systems keep the passwords in a separate file from the public user database. Linux uses `/etc/shadow`. You can put passwords in `/etc/passwd` (it's still supported for backward compatibility), but you have to reconfigure the system to do that.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36970/is-user-password-in-ubuntu-13-04-in-plain-text

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37050/where-is-my-password-stored-on-linux

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd#Password_file